# Is it true that as long as you have the public and private key for a bitcoin address, you are safe?

Tags: private-key, public-key, paper-wallet

So i created a public & private key on blockchain.info and printed it out as a paper wallet. Am I safe to say that no one can comprise it unless they physically get a hold of my piece of paper?

Also I want to be safe in the fact that I can redeem this public/private key by inputting it into one of the desktop applications? which ones would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a non-zero chance, that the communication protocol, blockchain.info or your computer have been compromised. (This chance is fairly low)

You don't have to show your private key to anybody until you want to withdraw/send money from this address. You can securely generate and print the key on an offline computer.

There is also chance, that someone will generate the same private key, this may be caused by faulty software or just a very bad fortune, but the probability is much lower than finding few blocks in a row.:)

Answer (score 0):

That is only true if you created it using the cold storage option on blockchain.info. Otherwise someone can get a hold of your bc wallet identifier and password and steal your bitcoins.

You can import your private key into any Bitcoin wallet.

You don't actually need the public key because it can be derived from the private key. So your private key also holds your public key.